# How to change default pushnotification alertview?

Tags: iphone

In my application i want to change the default alertview and hide the Cacel button from that alert view.
Is it possible in iphone ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide the cancel button but you *can* change it's text to whatever you want :

```
UIAlertView *myCustomAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                        message:@"Message"
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

That code will create an alert with a single 'OK' button.

Comment: it works when the application is open.But while the application is closed and pushnotification arrives at that time it is showing View and Cancel buttons in alertview. For that alert view what should i have to do?

Comment: Ah, I've not fully understood your question, sorry. I don't think you can change the notification UI at all (in fact, isn't it completely different in iOS5 anyway?)